# Динамическая загрузка jar в JVM

Tags: java, jvm

Пытаюсь динамически загрузить файл в JVM при помощи ClassLoader

```
File folder = new File(path);
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
URL[] urls = new URL[files.length];

for(int i = 0; i < files.length;i++) {
    urls[i] = files[i].toURI.toURL();
}

private ClassLoader classLoader;
classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Проблема в том, что внутри jar-файла находится еще один jar файл и он к сожалению в JVM не подгружается

Comment: так достань этот внутренний jar'ник (jar - это zip-архив) и добавь его в classloader

Comment: @Темкатоже спасибо за подсказку

Comment: А если грузить так `path/outer.jar!path/inner.jar`?